# calling different Action Method from another Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, navigation, html-helper, html.actionlink

I have a default Controller HomeController.cs having a `ActionLink`. I have a second controller StudentController.cs having several `ActionMethods`. I am trying to call the Student controller's `GetStudent` ActionMethod from Home controller's view but I get following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.

Home Controllers view code where I am using HTML Helper `ActionLink` to navigate

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Get Student Info", "Main", "Student")</p>
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Get Student Info", "GetStudent", "Student")`

Comment: Cool! Can you post answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method of `StudentController` is named `GetStudent`, then it needs to be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Student Info", "GetStudent", "Student")
```

The 2nd parameter is the name of the method your calling.